# Is Model Binder missing here? If YES, how to create and register with Global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I having below code for different artifacts,

**Entity**

```
public class ChooseFirst
{
    public int ChooseFirstId { get; set; }
    public string ChooseFirstName { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class SelectViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListChooseFirst { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller/Get Action**

```
//
    // GET: /MenuOne/

    public ActionResult MenuOne()
    {
        var selectViewModel = new SelectViewModel
                                  {
                                      ListChooseFirst = ChooseFirstList()
                                  };

        return View(selectViewModel);
    }
 private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ChooseFirstList()
    {
        //here data comes from database
        List<ChooseFirst> list = _getFComboService.GetFComboList();

        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (ChooseFirst chooseFirst in list)
        {
            SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();
            item.Text = chooseFirst.ChooseFirstName;
            item.Value = chooseFirst.ChooseFirstId.ToString();
            items.Add(item);
        }
        return items;
    }
```

**HTML View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("FCombo", Model.ListChooseFirst, "--Select One--")
```

Now Problem when I post my form the value for "selectViewModel" is NULL, Is there a need to model binder, please suggest and help me how to create Model Binder for this?

```
//
    // POST: /MenuOne/
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MenuOne(SelectViewModel selectViewModel)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is correct. all that is posted to the server is 'FCombo' with a value of the selected option. there is no enumeration of select list items. instead what you need is a view model for the posted data.

```
class SelectedOptionViewModel
{
    public int FCombo {get;set;}
}
```

or you can simply pass the parameter directly as an argument

```
public ActionResult MenuOne(int fcombo)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a property to bind the selected value of the dropdownlist to in your viewModel. You need something like:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItem, Model.ListChooseFirst)
```

You'll need to update your viewModel to add the SelectedItem property

```
    class SelectedOptionViewModel
{
    public int SelectedItem {get;set;}
}
```